How to deploy AWS Lambda function via Terragrunt without a source package?
I'm trying to deploy an AWS Lambda function using Terragrunt without attaching a zip package. The goal is to create the function with basic configurations and manage it directly through Terragrunt.
I've attempted setting create_package: false but Terragrunt throws an error Could not locate source_path "null". I tried using a dummy package with local_existing_package: "./dummy.zip" and ignore_source_code_hash: true, but the error persists.
Here’s what my configuration looks like:
1st Try:
- function_name: test-function
  create_package: false
  description: "test-function"
  handler: "lambda_handler"

2nd Try:
- function_name: test-function
  create_package: false
  local_existing_package: "./dummy.zip"
  ignore_source_code_hash: true
  description: "test-function"
  handler: "lambda_handler"


I believe this configuration should work:
- function_name: test-function
  create_package: false
  local_existing_package: "./dummy.zip"
  ignore_source_code_hash: true
  description: "test-function"
  handler: "lambda_handler"
  runtime: "python3.9"
  memory_size: 128

but there's one thing that concerns me, the local_existing_package should be the absolute path not the relative path.
variable "local_existing_package" {
  description = "The absolute path to an existing zip-file to use"
  type        = string
  default     = null
}

so try to use local_existing_package = "${abspath("./dummy.zip")}" instead
and clear the terragrunt cache before applying again :
rm -rf .terragrunt-cache


Solution

The issue was in the lambdas = try({}) block. Initially, only the function_name and options were being passed, while everything else was ignored.
After encountering the error (source_path "null"), I decided to debug the actual inputs being sent to the Lambda module. To do this, I added the following line:
debug_input_items = run_cmd("echo", "DEBUG: Items passed to module -> ${jsonencode(local.lambdas)}")

To my surprise, the debug revealed that only the function_name was being passed to the module. This explained why source_path was still null even when I explicitly set it to “something.”
To fix this, I updated the block to include all the necessary fields like runtime, handler, memory_size, and others. Additionally, because .hcl files don’t support $ for interpolation, I ensured that local_existing_package was handled dynamically by constructing its path based on the Lambda function name. Since you’ll typically use the same name for the ZIP file as the Lambda function, this approach simplifies the setup.
Here’s the updated block:
lambdas = try({
  for lambda in local.all_lambdas:
    "${include.root.locals.convention-naming}-${lambda.function_name}" => merge(
      {
        function_name           = "${include.root.locals.convention-naming}-${lambda.function_name}"
        create_package          = lambda.create_package
        local_existing_package  = abspath("${get_terragrunt_dir()}/${lambda.function_name}.zip")
        ignore_source_code_hash = lambda.ignore_source_code_hash
        description             = lambda.description
        handler                 = lambda.handler
        runtime                 = lambda.runtime
        memory_size             = lambda.memory_size
      },
      try(lambda.options, {})  # Include optional configurations
    )
}, {})

debug_input_items = run_cmd("echo", "DEBUG: Items passed to module -> ${jsonencode(local.lambdas)}")

I tested everything at my end and it's working.

Do not forget to add a non empty .py file within the zip file. just python file with print('Hello World!') will be enough
Thank you for uploading out the code and sorry for being a little bit late.

Can you upload your full code to git or upload it in a zip file somewhere?

Hey, any luck mate?

I updated the comment to add the solution

Thanks a lot. I'll try it. What do you have in your lambdas.yaml file now?

Same configuration, just removed the local_existing_package and added it within .hcl file. Hope you accept the solution if it works out for you.

great! it works. Thanks a mil!

Always, feel free to reach out whenever you want.

I have a question. I don't want to upload any source code file, as the Lambda already exists with the source code. However, when importing via Terragrunt, it uploads the new code file as well, which we are providing in the configuration. How can I import the resources without uploading the code file?

To import a resource without uploading Code, first run terragrunt plan to generate the .terragrunt-cache, then navigate to .terragrunt-cache/random-text/random-text. Inside, run terraform init, followed by terraform import with the required variables. You can get these variables fromdebug_input_items = run_cmd to your terragrunt.hcl. Import command will look like this: terraform import -var='var1=value1' -var='var2=value2' 'module.wrapper["c9-dev4-use1-asg-dns-update"].aws_lambda_function.this[0]' asg-dns-update , lastly remove the local_existing_package and add ignore_source_code_hash

Alternatively, you can copy the code locally, then import your Lambda using Terragrunt. After importing, delete the local code, set ignore_source_code_hash = true, and remove the local_existing_package variable from your configuration. This ensures Terragrunt manages the Lambda’s configuration without attempting to re-upload or validate the source code. i think this will be easier

there are 100s of functions. would be a nightmare to do that one by one :D

At least for copying local code, importing it, then delete the code again, you can create a python script to do it.

Hey, I'm thinking to implement this solution "...., followed by terraform import with the required variables. You can get these variables fromdebug_input_items = run_cmd to your terragrunt.hcl. Import command will look like this: terraform import -var='var1=value1' -var='var2=value2' 'module.wrapper["c9-dev4-use1-asg-dns-update"].aws_lambda_function.this[0]' asg-dns-update , lastly remove the local_existing_package and add ignore_source_code_hash".
what do you mean by -var='var1=value1' -var='var2=value2'? how can I get/use the values?

these are the values you're injecting to terraform with the use of Terragrunt with your lambda configuration within _common/lambda.yaml

if possible can you please give me an example?
